# Difference between passing the data type and executing an array without them

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just want to know if these 2 sets of code are doing the same thing or not, if not what's the difference?

```
$connect= new CONNECT();
$sql = ("query here");
$stmt = $connect->runQuery($sql);               
$stmt->bindParam(':sample', $_POST['sample'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':sample2', $_POST['sample2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':sample3', $_POST['sample3'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

=======================AND========================

```
$connect= new CONNECT();
$sql = ("query here");
$stmt = $connect->runQuery($sql);   
$stmt->execute(Array(
                    ':sample1'      =>  $_POST['sample'],
                    ':sample2'      =>  $_POST['sample2'],
                    ':sample3'      =>  $_POST['sample3']
                    ));
```

FYI, both work perfectly, just wanting to know if I'm getting the full security benefit using either one. Thanks.

Comment: The second is equivalent in this scenario. However, you need to note that the second method does not allow you to bind other datatypes (everything is considered `PDO::PARAM_STR`).

Comment: In addition to what @Phylogenesis noted, binding using the second method binds by value while the first one binds by reference which means using the first method you can re-use the same prepared statement and just modify the variable values to re-run the query using differnent parameters. (though the way you're using the first one makes this impossible)

Comment: @Phylogenesis - Arrh, thanks.
IS there a way to set the data type while using the array? I actually tried, and looked it up and I see no way.

Comment: @JohnMartin You could build an array that contains the `$_POST` data and the result from a [gettype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to generate yourself bound parameter types.

Comment: @WillParky93, If it costs more characters or system resources than the binParam line, I'll pass. Trying to make everything as economic as possible, so to speak. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: your post is contradictory. First you ask if they will both do the same thing, then state that it's working. So... what differences *did* you find between both?

Comment: *"FYI, both work perfectly, just wanting to know if I'm getting the full security benefit using either one."* - Is this what the question's really about?

Comment: you should mark off all your questions as solved btw. This helps to let people know that no more answers are required.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was simply stating that the queries all run successfully, with both ways, I'm very new to PDO and just wanted to make sure it was the same as far as the binding goes. Yes, this is what the question is about as it says, are they doing the same thing so I can know to keep doing the array as it looks neater IMO.

Comment: Fair enough John. However, I feel the question's title should reflect the real question. I have to go for a bit, but will think of something when I get back, unless you can think of a better one :-)

Comment: The typo does not help now, does it?? LMAO
"Are these sets of code both binding?" Maybe? lol

Comment: Thanks for voting it down though, I think a down vote is not really appropriate, not simply because of the main title, however, people think what they think...

Comment: @JohnMartin I changed the title. I think that better reflects what you're asking. However, I feel that this being a 2-part question, the answer below did not fully answer it and should be edited/modified IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By passing the parameters along with the `$stmt->execute()` method, all values in the array with be passed, as `PDO::PARAM_STR` to the statement with the `$stmt->bindParam()` function.

And  with the `$stmt->bindParam()` function, you can define the data type passed along, using the `PDO::PARAM_*`

Read more about [PDO::PARAM_](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

Comment: That is an awesome answer. So it is exactly the same, but always uses a default string datatype. Good thing string is a very common data type, lol.

Comment: *"FYI, both work perfectly, just wanting to know if I'm getting the full security benefit using either one."* - That was a 2-part question and should be answered, IMHO.

Comment: Well, I asked what the difference was and I now know. They array passes the default "String" datatype, whereas the bindParam allows you to set the datatype. I already got an answer in the first comment which basically says it is the same and this answer is basically the same. Perhaps if the words "**They both do the bindParam**, but one allows the the datatype to be set and the Array does not", may be better for the the audience, I suppose.